# How to get exact regex for accepting Number with alphabet only?

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I tried to get the exact regex for matching Number with alphabet only,
I tried this

```
 Regex.IsMatch("1111", @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
```

but the output is true.

Here is what I want output

```
12345678 -> False
abcdefgh -> False
ABCDEFGH -> False
1234abcd -> True
1234ABCD -> True
```

Comment: Do the letters always come after the numbers or can they be in any order?

Comment: any order at least have Numbers and letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following positive lookahead matching expression:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

This asserts that both grouped expressions are true and returns the full string on match.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/GxPPt9/2

Answer (score 1):

This will match any string that contains both numbers and letters, in whatever order:

```
^[[:alnum:]]*(([0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][0-9]))[[:alnum:]]*$
```

If you want you could replace `[[:alnum:]]` with `[A-Za-z0-9]`, this might be mandatory to get it working in C#, see the comments under this answer.

Try it out: https://regex101.com/r/yj9sWw/2

Comment: Good, now you can remove useless capture groups and use non-capturing group for the one that is needed.

Comment: I just realize that .net doesn't support POSIX character classes like `[:alnum:]`, so you must write `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a non-regex approach counting the neumber of letter-chars and digit-chars:

```
bool ContainsOnlyDigitsAndLetters(string source)
{
    int letters = myInput.Count(Char.IsLetter);
    int numbers = myInput.Count(Char.IsDigit);
    return letters != 0 && numbers != 0 && letters + numbers == myInput.Length;
}
```

This returns `true` if your inout is mixed up, false if it either contains only numbers or only letters or if there are chars within the string that are neither the one nor the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write:

```
^(?>[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B%7C%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%29%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%24&i=0h)

Here the atomic group `(?>...)` prevents the regex engine to backtrack, since the quantifier `+` is greedy, the next character matched by `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` is different from the one matched in the alternation. When the branch `[0-9]+` succeeds, the first character matched by `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` can only be a letter, when `[a-zA-Z]+` succeeds, the first character matched by `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` can only be a digit.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
a-zA-Z0-9
```

to

```
\w+\d+

@"^[\w+\d+]+$"
```

EDIT:

If numbers are always before characters so simple:

```
(\d+\w+)
```

Comment: matches `_` aswell (`\w` matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore)

Comment: Regex.IsMatch("12345678", @"^[\w+\d+]+$") returns true it must be return false

Comment: Oh. ok sorry, i misunderstood :) Edited.

Comment: `(\d+\w+)` matches e.g. `123`